# Solve the SDE $dX_t=\alpha \,dt + \sigma X_t \,dB_t$, $X_0=x_0$

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

So I got the following SDE to solve:

$$dX_t=\alpha\, dt + \sigma X_t \,dB_t, X_0=x_0$$

This is what I've tried:

Using Ito's I should get the following relations:

$$X_t=f(s,x)$$
$$\alpha = \frac{1}{2}\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}+\frac{df}{ds}$$
$$\sigma X_t=\frac{df}{dx}$$

The second equation, which seems to be a ODE:

$$\frac{df}{dx}-\sigma X_t=\frac{df}{dx}-\sigma f=0$$
Using the integrating factor:
$$I = e^{\int -\sigma \,dx}=e^{-\sigma x + g(s)}$$
$$\frac{df}{dx}I-\sigma fI=0$$
$$(fI)'=0$$
$$f=CI^{-1}$$
Using the initial value:
$$f(0,0)=x_0=C$$
$$f=x_0e^{-\sigma x + g(s)}$$
The problem for me is now to solve $g(s)$.

Differentiating by $x$ twice and $s$ once gives:
$$\frac{df}{ds}=g'(s)f$$
$$\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}=\sigma^2f$$
$$\alpha = \frac{1}{2}\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}+\frac{df}{ds}$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2f+g'(s)f=\alpha$$

At this point I'm quite unsure on what to do.

Comment: Ye I checked and solved the problem. Think you where the one who solved it if I'm not mistaken? I had to sort the steps that you jumped over though to fully understand. Should I submit a solution or just redirect it?